# Calculate $Var(X|Y=10)$

Tags: probability

I am given $f(x,y) = {1\over 1250},\;0< x < y
< 50$

I need to calculated $Var(X|Y=10)$

---

My Attempt:

$$f(x|y=10)={{1\over1250}\over \int_0^{50}{1\over1250}dx}$$ When I solve this and do the calculation, I get $208.333$ which doesn't seem right to me.

Answer (score 1):

Fixing $Y$, $X$ has a uniform distribution from $1$ to $10$, right? Its variance should therefore be $\frac{1}{12}(10-0)^2$, or $8.\overline{3}$.

In your calculation, since we have $x<y$, the restriction $Y=10$ means you shouldn't be integrating $x$ from $0$ to $50$. The support of this distribution is a triangle in the $xy$-plane, and we're looking at a slice of it with width $10$.

---

$$\begin{align}\require{enclose}f_{X\mid Y=10}(x) ~&=~ \dfrac{\tfrac 1{1250}\quad[0<x<10]}{\int_0^{\color{red}{\enclose{circle}{\color{black}{10~}}}}\tfrac 1{1250}\operatorname d s}\\[3ex] &=~\tfrac 1{10}\quad[0<x<10]\end{align}$$